# How to show text above image using css

Tags: html, css

I tried to show text over image but it doesn't work for me
this is my code

```css
 .banner{
          background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.6),rgba(0,0,0,.6)),url(img/aboutus/s4.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          background-attachment: scroll;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          height: 80vh;
          position: relative;
      }
      
      .img{
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          width: 100%;
      }
     .info h5{
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 15;
          top: 0;
          left: 50%;
      }
```

```html
    <section class="banner" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="info">
                <h5>about us </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img class="img" src="img/aboutus/home_overlay.png">
    </section>
```

Result is displayed without text

[image]

**how to solve this issue** *and sorry for bad English*.

Comment: try the z-index on the container instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution with minimal formatting, so it is easier to edit.

```css
  .background {
    background: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/xTiTnxpQ3ghPiB2Hp6/giphy.gif) repeat;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 175px;
  }
  .info {
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="background">
    <p class="info">About Us</p>
  </div>
```